# Issue configuring Azure AD B2C with Asp.net Core 2 Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have downloaded the sample code https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/core2.0

I have changed the `appSettings.json` file to use the values for my Tenant and Web Application.

However, when I try to login, I am redirected to the redirect URI that is setup in the policy I'm using.

I am really confused as to why it won't redirect to the default page for the SignIn-SignUp policy. Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of errors are in the URL.  What is the exact URL you are redirected to?

Comment: As @spottedmahn outlined, if there are errors with your request, Azure AD B2C will reply back to the redirect URI with an error in the query string. Can you enable developer tools (F12 on the browser) and see what's being sent in the request to Azure AD B2C and what the response is? Please include a screenshot of that along with the request/response in your question.

Comment: @Gavin Gant, Is there any problem about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The **SignIn-SignUp** policy doesn't define the **redirect URL**. It you mean the **Select reply URL** when you test the policy on the Azure portal like figure below, it is defined in the app you register. And when you check the exact URL under **Run now endpoint**, you should also could see that the redirect URL is passed as the parameter **redirect_uri** just same as the web app do.

[image]